# ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/Desktop/node_modules'

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

An unhandled exception occurred:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 
'/Users/Desktop/node_modules'
See "/private/var/folders/3p/l_k1wk8n76v3cfwnxk0blx000000gn/T/ng- 
DF5EZ7/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Whenever I am doing `ng serve`, this error occurs.

Can anyone tell me what is the cause of error?

Comment: Are you running the command in the root of your project folder?

Comment: yes, previously it was running, after some when again i did ng serve , this error is showing, i had to create new project but in that too after another ng serve this same error occuring,  why this is happening.

Comment: if your project can be uploaded to github or somewhere else that would be the best, but the error may persint in the package.json file. Please try to rerunn npm install again

Comment: I got that error, but was because I had an additional console running "ng serve".

Answer (score 69):

I had this problem, it was just:

1. Works
   "styles": [
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
2. Not works
   "styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: in my case i uninstall a module and forgot to remove css file in `angular.json`

Answer (score 31):

I had the same error when I tried installing an old version of bootstrap and referenced it in the `angular.json` file. Meanwhile, the package was never installed because it doesn't exist anymore. Check the new command for installing a particular package and after doing `npm i <package-name> check in node_modules` if it's there.

And also, I changed my bootstrap path
from

```
../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
```

to

```
node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
```

Answer (score 8):

I got into this issue after installing ngx-bootstrap

```
> ng add ngx-bootstrap
```

Following went in angular.json

```
"styles": [
 "./dist/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
 "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
 "src/styles.css"
]
```

Changed to following and error got fixed

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
]
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, my problem was a misspelling issue in the directory URL inside Angular.json. So I corrected the error and the apps run perfectly afterwards.

**Not working:** (misspelled on "node_modules")

```
"styles": ["./node_moodules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"]
```

**Working:**

```
"styles": ["./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"]
```

try checking your url path in Angular.json, this probably the case, hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Solving the problems on `angular.json` then deleting `package-lock.json` solved my problem.

My problem was related to a deleted package `@angular/material`. Angular.json styles were still referencing that package, I deleted those lines. Then I deleted the `package-lock.json` and execute it.

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

`npm install --force` and then `npm audit fix --force`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. But I found a Solution which works for me.

Try:

> npm install --save bootstrap

and then add in **angular.json** at "styles":

> "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

run the Project (**Watch if youre in the right folder you can check it with typing in terminal ls and and then you should see node_modules, src etc.**)

> ng serve

Comment: Non other than this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

if: **npm install bootstrap**
then **"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"**

if **npm install --save bootstrap**
then **"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"**

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar error:

```
 An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 
'C:\User_Name\Angular\node_modules\bootstrap'
See "C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-MhR1Ls\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

This was caused due to adding this in styles array:

```
    "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ]
```

**Solved it by changing styles array with**

```
    "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ]
```

This may have happened cause I made another angular project inside the parent folder or directory since "." denotes the home directory.
This is just my understanding and the solution of the issue.

**Please check whether you have added your current component.html file i.e. unique selector in your app.component.html file**

Recently started my angular journey so cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Download manually bootstrap from https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap .
2. Copy and past the folder you download to /Users/Desktop/node_modules .
3. In CMD, enter to your project folder you created by typing: CD yourProjectName .
4. In CMD: ng serve.
5. In your browser: http://localhost:4200/

Answer (score 1):

In my case i removed the "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" from angular.json

Answer (score 1):

As @Manuel Villadiego said, you must define your bootstrap path like below:

"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Or

"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

This error will happen when you start bootstrap path with ../ ,

"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

because you go back one folder and node_modules folder doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm had the same problem with my angular project after installing Boostrap.

My approach was:

angular.json file should have this under styles. `"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.css"`

Then import in the main style.css file.

```
@import url('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Make sure the path for node_modules is correct,

After making those changes I ran `ng serve` or `npm start`
[image: Angular app is running]

Answer (score 1):

check angular.json file. sometimes style css pointing to the node modules may be incorrect

```
 "styles": [
 "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
        ],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue could be one of many flavors.
Mine was specifically, in the relative path of `bootstrap.min.css` that was specified in `angular.json`

The error message that I had in the logs was:
`"[error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\arsth\node_modules'"`

I was following a tutorial video and provided the path as `../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

But in my project, the `angular.json` file is actually at the same level as the `node_modules` folder. So correcting the above entry to
`./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`
solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a non-Angular project; here's what worked for me:

1. update node and npm
2. delete package-lock.json
3. run `npm install --package-lock-only`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it happens when

> package-lock.json

was created by another version of the `node js` (I'm using the latest LTS version).

***Just remove it and try again, this is OK.***

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, I removed the followings from angular.json which I had just added and the issue is resolved.

```
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "src/styles/styles.scss",
          "src/styles/colors.scss"
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) `npm install --save bootstrap`

Step 2) and then add in angular.json at "styles":
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",

Step 3) `ng serve`

Problem solved

[image: image showing the solution]

Answer (score 0):

I removed the file from `angular.json` and added it to `style.css`.

```
@import '../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Angular.js & Wrong Directions.

First of all, open a file called `angular.js` in the root folder.

And check if you add some wrong Directory. like the style or something like that. as example.

Suppose you add the bootstrap dependency and you want to add it to your project you will go to the angular.js and add it in the style configuration. so you will add it as the below:

```
 "styles": [
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

Check if you add double **dot** `..` not one dot in the path like the below:

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
```

### Correct format is as the below :

```
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
```

Answer (score 0):

In the angular.json file just do this change :

"styles" : [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"src/styles.css" ]

Answer (score 0):

remove all node_module or remove node_moules folder and type
npm install

Answer (score 0):

Bumped against the same issue with the quickstart tutorial. After restarting the tutorial and using yarn instead of npm, everything seems working fine.

Answer (score 0):

On my project, I use bootstrap with SCSS and changing the path
from  `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/scss/bootstrap.scss"`
to `"node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"`
helped me with this error.

PS. I deleted the dist folder from path.

Answer (score -2):

You need to check with the path of bootstrap in angular.json inside architect then styles

Comment: Please answer with examples or more guidance

Comment: We appreciate your vague and generic answer mate.
- Next time kindly be elaborate as what path should be edited from what to what.  You go ahead and finish, ...`then styles`, Which styles dude? Anyways, thank you.